# how to fix htaccess to friendly url

Tags: .htaccess

i tried different code in order to convert url to friendly url, but its doesnt seems working. here is my code the recent in tried.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

i would like to use instead of id to friendly text which could be the title of the page.

my current link is as follows

```
http://example.com/website/425199399/
```

i am exception the link something like this

```
http://example.com/website/the-working-class-family-425199399
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you posted does not even attempt to implement a rewrite s you sketched it...

Here is a version that should point you into the right direction, but you certainly will have to adopt it to our needs and specific situation. So you won't get around reading into the documentation of the tools you use. You will find that the documentation of the apache modules (her the rewriting module) are of excellent quality and offer really good examples...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?website/.+-(\d+)$ /website/$1 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).